# Android Vitals. "Session" and "crash free users"

Tags: android, session, developer-console

Hello, everybody! 
I have some questions to Android Vitals. 
What is "session" mean? Maybe "session" in Android Vitals is equaled to "session" in Crashlytics? Or "session" is equaled to "session" in Google Analytics? 
I want to understand concept "session" on an example. I use application within 20 minutes. After that, I use other applications within 2 hours. After that, I use my application within 30 minutes. And after that, I block my phone and don't use the phone until the end of the day. How many sessions will be as a result?
Another question. How does Android Vitals calculate "crash free sessions"? I use my app within 5 minutes and after that, there is the crash? But the app is restarted in 10 seconds. How many sessions will be and how many sessions with crash will be a result? 
Can I have the opportunity to calculate "crash free users" in Android Vitals independently? And I can't find total numbers of sessions?

Comment: IMO, a session starts when first activity starts and ends when the no activity is present in the application.

Comment: @NabinBhandari ok. And what about background mode? Is it "session" or not? And how long app may be in background mode within only ONE session?

Comment: sorry, not sure about that. but again in my guess is the same condition for background service too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/android-vitals.html#key-metrics

> Stability | Crash rate: The percentage of users who experienced at least one crash event during a daily session. Crashes are often caused by unhandled exceptions, resource exhaustion, failed assertions, or other unexpected states.

Meaning in a one specific day, if your user opened an app couple times and experienced at least one crash - his session will be considered as crashed and will be included in statistics as crash-affected user
If during the day all foreground sessions, a user does not experience any crash - he considered as a crash-free user.

In General - "session" is a period of time when a process is running in foreground up till it's being killed.

Comment: I think that the definition is not correct! the Crash-free users represent the percentage of users who **NOT** experienced a crash

Comment: @rdiaz82 I've revised this answer, as you're correct - the definition here didn't match Google's article.